# Changes to array of JSON objects based on other array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array of JSON objects that look like this:

```
{"id":1,"place":2,"pic_name":"aaa.jpg"}
```

My PHP file receives a simple array like:

```
["4","3","1","2","5"]
```

These numbers correspond to the place value in my JSON object. Now I need to compare the place of each element in the secont array with the value of ID in the JSON object and if the match I have to replace the value of PLACE with the element from the array.
I am having problems doing the comparison. Any guidelines? What I come up with:

```
foreach($ids as $index=>$id) { //the array
$id = (int) $id;
foreach ($obj as $key=>$value) { //the JSON objects
  foreach ($value as $k=>$v){ 
  if ($id != '' && array_search($index, array_keys($ids)) == $value[$k]['id'])  {
      $value[$k]['place'] = $id;
      file_put_contents($file, json_encode($ids));
    } else { print "nope";}  
  }  }  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will be:

```
$array = [
'{"id":1,"place":2,"pic_name":"aaa.jpg"}',
'{"id":2,"place":5,"pic_name":"aab.jpg"}',
'{"id":3,"place":1,"pic_name":"aba.jpg"}',
'{"id":4,"place":3,"pic_name":"baa.jpg"}',
'{"id":5,"place":4,"pic_name":"abb.jpg"}'
];
$places = ["4","3","1","2","5"];

$array = array_map(function($item)
{
   return json_decode($item, 1);
}, $array);
foreach($array as $i=>$jsonData)
{
   if(false!==($place=array_search($jsonData['id'], $places)))
   {
      $array[$i]['place'] = $place+1;
   }
}
$array = array_map('json_encode', $array);
//var_dump($array);
```

-with output like:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(39) "{"id":1,"place":3,"pic_name":"aaa.jpg"}"
  [1]=>
  string(39) "{"id":2,"place":4,"pic_name":"aab.jpg"}"
  [2]=>
  string(39) "{"id":3,"place":2,"pic_name":"aba.jpg"}"
  [3]=>
  string(39) "{"id":4,"place":1,"pic_name":"baa.jpg"}"
  [4]=>
  string(39) "{"id":5,"place":5,"pic_name":"abb.jpg"}"
}
```